# How can I check if an anti-static wrist strap works?

Tags: esd

I bought Belkin's anti-static wristband but i must be sure it works, since sometimes people report getting units that are defective or do not work in reality.

I have laptop only. How to check if anti-static wristband works?

**UPDATE:** I have tested anti-static wrist strap with multimeter with resistance set on 2M and the result was **0.983**

Is this normal?

Comment: Use a multi-meter to see if there's a constant resistance between the metal contact plate on the wristband and the ground connector.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @billc.cn And i cannot test with continuity?

Comment: What do you mean by "continuity"?

Comment: Skip it, i can't do that.

Comment: It won't have "*continuity*" in the sense of near-zero resistance - it intentionally has a resistance to ground. So *can* check resistance (as opposed to continuity setting on some multimeters)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

Use an ohmmeter or multimeter to determine if there is conductivity between the metal part of the wrist strap, and the end part where you connect it to ground.  You should see some measurable resistance (indicating good conductivity) if the strap is functioning correctly.  If the resistance is *extremely* high (or as some meters measure, infinite), then the strap is broken.

Alternatively, you can just use it as a "wire" in conjunction with something else (e.g. an LED) and determine if you can provide power through the anti-static wrist strap.  If current can flow through it, it's working, since that is all the device is used for (to provide a quick path to ground for your skin).

Comment: If the wrist strap has a current limiting safety resistor in line - which it should - the end-end resistance will be very **HIGH**, not low - perhaps 1-10M Ohms.

Comment: @Linker3000 that is correct.  Do note that if you're working on a computer system, you should use a wrist strap with a lower resistance in series with the strap (higher isn't always better when working with low voltage devices).

Answer (score 8):

Get a Van der Graaf generator and put your hand on it while you have your anti-static wrist band on (and shoes) and then get someone to go up to touch you.  If they get a shock, it does not work.  If your hair stands on end, that would be another sign that it does not work.

I have no idea where you could get a Van der Graaf generator, but this test should work if you manage to do so.

[image: static hair]

Comment: Shame you can't give points for creativity! Is the girl with long hair essential - I only habe an 11 year old son with short hair.

Comment: @Linker3000: I think long hair makes a better indicator of the presence of static electricity (and therefore the failure of the anti-static wristband).  You should get your son to grow his hair if you want to use him for testing.

Comment: Of course, there is the possibility the wrist strap may not be the path of least resistance when that other person grabs you. The wrist strap is only as good as the ground it is connected to.

Comment: This is one of the best answers . .

Answer (score 0):

This is only a theory, but since laptop trackpads only work with things with an electric charge (Eg, your finger), an antistatic wristband could cause it not to recognize your finger, thus proving it works. Remember, just a theory, so if it doesn't work don't blame me.